# Found 60000 input samples and 10000 target samples.How to solve this error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

this is code i got from tensorflow tutorial on tensorflow website. halfway through i got this error.
ii succesfully trained the model . but when test images are passed i get error.

````
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fashion_mnist= keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
train_images=train_images/255.0
test_images=train_images/255.0
model=keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)```

this code gives the following error:

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 60000 input samples and 10000 target samples.
````

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory but you should still post the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_images=train_images/255.0
```

Should instead be:

```
test_images=test_images/255.0
```

Otherwise you are dividing train_images by 255, then diving that by 255 again

Answer (score 1):

Because you made a typo while normalizing:

```
test_images=train_images/255.0
```

Instead of:

```
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```